# Why is renderRequest.contextPath empty in config.jsp but not view.jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-6

I'm new to liferay and java so this is probably very simple.

I've successfully created portlet complete with a configuration.jsp file.  In my portlet view.jsp I can successfully reference images:

```
<img src="${renderRequest.contextPath}/images/image1.png" />
```

But in my configuration.jsp the contextPath is empty.

QUESTION: What needs to be done in order to get the same path I get in my view.jsp?

I've created this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/S0uCpCpg) showing my full code and this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/LwBnPtdV) to show a simpler case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/image1.png"/>
```

Ensure that you have configured the portlet name properly in portlet.xml and web.xml

Comment: My web.xml looks like this:

<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
</web-app>

Comment: Since it works in view.jsp but not configuration.jsp I'm guessing it's not because of a misnamed portlet or because I'm using contextPath instead of getContextPath() but I confirmed it is named correctly in portlet.xml and will replace the property with the method.

Comment: The output is the same, for configuration.jsp it is <img src="//images/image1.png"> and for view.jsp it is <img src="/thenameofmy-portlet/images/image1.png" id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1444411195293_2583">

Comment: Can you just check the image (/thenameofmy-portlet/images/image1.png) is available in the mentioned path by hitting the URL in web browser? If it's available, it should be accessible in jsp also with proper path.

Comment: I can see it on the view.jsp but not the configuration.jsp page.  Yes, it also exists in the file system.  The problem is getContextPath() is returning an empty string.